# How to display class name in this shortcode post query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I need help with this as it's my first project of my new job & I'm stuck at this point.

I'm retrieving custom post types portfolio using this code as a shortlist:

```
extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => -1, 'type' => 'post'), $atts ) );

$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  

query_posts(  array ( 
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
    'post_type' => $type, 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' =>'menu_order', 
    'paged' => $paged ) );

$list = ' ';   

while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

    $list .= '<li class="mix all">' 
    . '<div class="listing-content">' 
    . '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>' 
    .'<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>'
    . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'View &raquo;' . '</a>'
    . '</div>'
    . '<a class="listing-thumb" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'listing-thumb')  . '<span></span></a>'
    . '</article>';
}

return 
'<div class="listings clearfix">' 
. $list 
. '<div class="nav-previous">' . get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) . '</div>'
. '<div class="nav-next">' . get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) . '</div>'
. '</div>' .
wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode( 'feed', 'section_feed_shortcode' );
```

I want to display the custom taxonomy "name" at the following point of code:

```
$list .= '<li class="mix all ####RIGHT HERE#### ">'
```

Is it possible to do. If yes, then featured image as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Taxonomy or terms assigned to given post? What is the taxonomy name?

Comment: Terms assigned to given post.

Comment: port_tags is the taxonomy name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you have to modify some part of your code like so:

```
$list = ' ';

while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'port_tags' );
    $terms_string = '';
    if ( $terms ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term )
            $terms_string .= $term->slug . ' ';
    }

    $list .= '<li class="mix all '. $terms_string .'">' 
    . '<div class="listing-content">' 
    . '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>' 
    .'<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>'
    . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'View &raquo;' . '</a>'
    . '</div>'
    . '<a class="listing-thumb" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'listing-thumb')  . '<span></span></a>'
    . '</article>';  // <- it should be </li> not </article>, I guess - you don't open any <article> tag in this loop
}
```

Comment: No problem, Hardeep :)

Comment: How to retrieve featured image of this custom post type?

Comment: Use the_post_thumbnail function.

Comment: I have tried to use it, but it's working everywhere but in this code.

Comment: Could you show your code? How have you tried to use this function?

Comment: I have used this: $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );

Comment: Okay, I got this thing as well. Thanks for the help :)